# How to split string with multiple paragraphs and return arbitrary string within ES6 class syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I would like to split this poem excerpt into an array.

```
The stiff spokes of this wheel
touch the sore spots of the earth.

On the Potomac, swan-white
power launches keep breasting the sulphurous wave.

Otters slide and dive and slick back their hair,
raccoons clean their meat in the creek.

On the circles, green statues ride like South American
liberators above the breeding vegetation—

prongs and spearheads of some equatorial
backland that will inherit the globe.

The elect, the elected . . . they come here bright as dimes,
and die dishevelled and soft.
```

In the new array, I want to see the output look like this:

```
[
    "The stiff spokes of this wheel
    touch the sore spots of the earth.",
    
    "On the Potomac, swan-white
    power launches keep breasting the sulphurous wave.",
    
    "[more strings below]"
]
```

If I receive the poem as one long string, how what do I use to split the string into an array of substrings with each paragraph as its own string?

The point is that I need to be able to arbitrarily target any substring, with a call like this:

```
new Poem().targetingMethod(3)
```

which would output the string

```
"On the circles, green statues ride like South American
liberators above the breeding vegetation—"
```

What I can't figure out how is how to split the original multi-paragraph string to keep the formatting of carriage returns in the middle of each poem verse, as well as splitting on the blank space/carriage return between each verse.

The expected format I want to use is the newer ES6 class syntax.

Thanks!

Poem source: https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/53020/july-in-washington

Comment: To handle edge cases, probably want it to be more like `\n{2,}`

Comment: What does it matter that you want this as part of a class? How to write a class is a) explained in the docs b) not part of your question - edit: it is now, I still don't understand why this is an issue. Have you tried *anything* yet?

Comment: @ChrisG I updated my question since I am looking to understand how this kind of thing works in the newer ES6 class syntax. It's not straightforward to me.

Comment: So do you want a poem class? And put the original string in the constructor? https://jsfiddle.net/ajLe8ngm/

Comment: @ChrisG hmm, that does look like what I was asking. That helps me understand better, thank you!

Comment: Oh, and now I also understand what I didn't know. Inside of template literals, what I was doing also wasn't working because the lyrics of the poem were formatted to line up vertically. I had to tab back everything to the first character space of the new line to fix an additional problem. Good to know!